# Processing serial connection NullPointerException

Tags: nullpointerexception, processing

I got this code which try to read a data from a serial connection from an Arduino Program, when I try to run it, it gave me NullPointerException after a few seconds of printing the outpout and it pointer to the `myVal = float(val);`

this is the processing code:

```
import processing.serial.*;

Serial myPort;  // Create object from Serial class
String val;     // Data received from the serial port
float myVal = 0;

void setup()
{
  String portName = Serial.list()[6];
  myPort = new Serial(this,portName,9600);
}


void draw()
{
 while (myPort.available() > 0)
 {
    val = myPort.readStringUntil('\n');
    if (myPort != null)
    {
      myVal = float(val);
      println(myVal);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How did it go in the end ? Did the answer bellow help ?

Answer (score 0):

It might be that val is null, not the port.

Slightly off topic, I'd advise not using a block while loop in draw().

Check out [serialEvent()](https://processing.org/reference/libraries/serial/serialEvent_.html) and [try...catch](https://www.javatpoint.com/try-catch-block)

example code:

```
import processing.serial.*;

Serial myPort;  // Create object from Serial class
String val;     // Data received from the serial port
float myVal = 0;

void setup()
{
  try{
    String portName = Serial.list()[6];
    myPort = new Serial(this,portName,9600);
    myPort.bufferUntil('\n');
  }catch(Exception e){
    println("error opening serial port ");
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}


void draw()
{
 background(0);
 text("myVal = " + myVal,5,15);
}

void serialEvent(Serial p) { 
  val = myPort.readString();
  try{
    //get read of newline chars (\n\r), if any
    val.trim();

    myVal = float(val);

  }catch(Exception e){
    println("error parsing serial string");
    e.printStackTrace();
  }

}
```